# Google speech recognition API and language model

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, recognizer-intent

I have seen the undocumented API for speech recognition from Google (https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?)

My assumption is that Android RecognizerIntent uses the same API.

Since the Android has ability to specify language model (only one of two available for now), I wonder if it is possible to specify the language model in the Google API?

I want to record and send speech for recognition concurrently, which is now not available in the official API